# Layover at Narita, Japan. Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, japan, nrt

I will be transferring between two international flights at Tokyo Narita airport. I'm scheduled to depart the same day I arrive. I am planning to stay within the airport during the layover. Does anyone know if I will require a transit visa at Narita?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17328/do-i-need-a-japanese-transit-visa-when-arriving-at-narita-and-departing-from-han

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No visa is required for transiting in Japanese airports if you have immediate flight connections regardless of nationality.

Anyway, there is a [Japanese transit visa](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/transit%20visas.html) which is intended for people who have longer layovers before transiting and want to go sightseeing or resting in Japan for few days (up to 15 days).

Comment: Apparently, if you have an overnight layover, you will need a transit visa. See [SSS's comment](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa/11340#11340) below.

Comment: @VarunVats The OP is not having an over night layover so I answered according to that. He is having an immediate connection flight and he does not need visa for that.

Answer (score 16):

I am an Indian passport holder working in the US on H1B. I was supposed to fly LAX-Narita-KL-Bangalore on 23rd December 2012 with a 14 hour overnight layover in Narita.

I received a call from the airline 2 days before my scheduled departure, stating that new rules at Narita dictate that **travelers *absolutely* need a transit visa for overnight layovers** in Narita, even if the arriving and departing flights are from the same terminal.

Because of the short notice, there was no time to apply for a Japanese transit visa (the Japanese consulate takes 3 working days to issue one).  I had to cancel my ticket and book a flight with Cathay, transiting thru' Hong Kong which has no transit visa requirements.

Comment: what is the definition of "overnight"?

Comment: Narita is closed to flights between 11 PM and 6 AM.  While officially 'closed' to passengers as well -- hence the overnight visa requirement -- in practice passengers are allowed to stay in the terminal though.

Comment: "overnight" simply means not within the same calendar day.

Answer (score 9):

A **stopover** is typically a stay in one city of 24 hours or more. In your case, you actually have just a **connection** in Tokyo. Connections can even go across airports in the same metropolitan area, such as between London's Heathrow and Gatwick airports.

*Very rarely* are visas required for connections in the same airport, since you do not need to clear immigration and customs. One exception is in the USA, where all passengers must clear immigration and customs, so check with your travel agent or local Embassy/Consulate for more information.

From my experience, you will not need a visa for this connection, since you are probably flying Japan Airlines and American Airlines, which are located in the same terminal (T2) at Narita. (Even if you're on Air India, they fly into T2 as well.) You will be required to show your boarding pass for NRT-DFW and clear security upon arrival in Tokyo, but you will not clear immigration and customs.

As ***MeNoTalk*** mentioned, if you do have a stopover in Japan, you can get a [Japanese Transit Visa](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/transit%20visas.html).

Comment: Related terminology question: [In the context of air travel, are layovers different to stopovers?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7144/in-the-context-of-air-travel-are-layovers-different-to-stopovers)

Comment: Another reason for needing a visa when connecting is if it's overnight, and the airside closes! Not normally a problem with bigger transit airports, but could bite you at a very small one...

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers suggest, you do **not** need a visa to transit at Narita, as stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=jp&SUBSECTION=TW&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for holders of onward tickets transiting on the
>     same calendar day.

**Important** to note, however, is that a transit visa is also **not** required for an overnight transfer (even though Narita's transit area closes at night) even for those normally needing a visa to enter Japan. Rather, by presenting your passport and onward ticket to immigration, you get a 72-hour entry stamp known as a Shore Pass.

> Holders of onward tickets transiting to a third country can
>     obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a max. stay of 72 hours
>     only if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar
>     day