# Do I need a transit visa at Narita airport? I am an Indian citizen travelling from South Korea to India

Tags: visas, japan, transit, indian-citizens, nrt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Layover at Narita, Japan. Do I need a transit visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa)

The flight of Japan airlines from Seoul arrives at Narita on 14th Feb 4 pm and flight for Delhi departs on 15th Feb 11.25 am. The halt is of almost 20 hrs.

Comment: In any case, [the answer can be found there](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/11340/583): you need a transit visa for *overnight layovers* in Narita but not otherwise, so in your case, **yes**, you need one.