# Do I need a Japanese transit visa when arriving at Narita and departing from Haneda?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, japan

I am arriving from New Delhi, India (with an Indian passport) on JAL at Narita Airport on July 11th at 7:30 AM and departing for San Francisco on JAL at 12:05 AM on July 12th from Haneda Airport. Do I need a transit visa since I will be switching airports and spending a few hours at the JAL City Haneda Airport Hotel?

Previously, I had connecting flights from Narita to San Francisco and obtained shore passes to relax at the Narita Nikko Hotel. Now, I am travelling with my elderly mother and do not want any complications at Narita immigration or later in the day while travelling from Narita Airport to Haneda Airport.

Comment: You will need a visa that allows you to get through the immigration control - whatever visa you are able to get as an Indian citizen. There is no way to get to Haneda airport without that.

Comment: A warning for current (2022) readers of this old question: the answers below may not currently apply due to Covid restrictions still in place. You most likely need a visa to transit between HND and NRT, and Japan currently has many restrictions on the types of visas they deliver. Check for more recent information if you are making such plans.

Answer (score 10):

Old post, but for posterity:

You do **not** need a transit visa if there aren't any possible connections for your itinerary on the same day **and** you arrive and depart from an airport within the same region.

In this case, by presenting your passport and connecting boarding pass or e-ticket, you get an entry stamp on arrival permitting you to stay in Japan for 72 hours.

From [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=jp&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Holders of onward tickets transiting to a third country can
>     obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a max. stay of 72 hours
>     only if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar
>     day

Narita and Haneda are located in the same region (called "group" in Timatic)

> Group A:
>     Airports: **Narita (NRT)**, **Haneda (HND)**, Nagoya (NGO), Niigata
>     (KIJ), Komatsu (KMQ) and Yokota.

So again, you do **not** need a visa

Comment: This should be upvoted to the top

Comment: how about the luggage, usually we don't need to handle the check in luggage during the stopover, do we need to take the luggage during the transit from Haneda and Narita? I am traveling from Beijing to Boston but the flight will stop at Haneda and then continue from Narita.

Comment: @peterboston THen you will need to pick it up, as automatically transferring it between airports is not a thing

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a regulation (cited [here](http://visados.com/en/visa-for-Japan) and [here](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/14488023-post32.html), but I could not find an authoritative source) saying that you can get a "transit pass" for exactly this purpose.

But to be on the safe side, I would get a [transit visa](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/transit%20visas.html) anyway - link is to the Japanese embassy in India, and it sounds like it is relatively cheap and easy to get.

Comment: thank you Michael.. you've clarified what various authorities in New Delhi could not do.. i'll get transit visas to be on the safe side.. i'm returning via haneda from sfo and  leaving for New Delhi from Narita after a fortnight.. i guess i'll require two sets of transit visas

Comment: For reference, the relevant legislation regarding the "shore pass" are Article 15 of the Immigration Act and Article 14 of the ministerial ordinance for its implementation, which are available in English [here](http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail/?id=1934&vm=&re=02) and [here](http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail/?id=1901&vm=04&re=02). (Those translations are based on out-of-date versions of the texts, but those particular articles are still current.)