# Transport between Haneda International Airport to Narita International Airport

Tags: airport-transfer, transit-visas, tokyo, nrt, hnd

Since I have no experience with my booked trip, my trip is San Francisco (U.S.)> Haneda(Japan then Narita(Japan)> HCMC(Vietnam).  Online resources said I have to transport between Haneda International Airport and Narita International Airport. My layover is only 5 hours.

What do I need for transportation? How can I get from Haneda to Narita?

If anyone can give me some advice, I really appreciate it.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17328/do-i-need-japanese-transit-visa-when-arriving-at-narita-and-departing-from-haned for the transit visa thing

Comment: What is your citizenship?  The answer linked by @MarkMayo is applicable to Indian citizens.

Comment: My close vote is that, absent nationality, it is difficult to answer. So, either close as unclear, or dupe to MarkMayo comment.