# Short stay transit visa at Narita Airport, Japan

Tags: visas, japan, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino and traveling to the USA on a K-1 visa with a stop in Narita.  My layover is 3 hours, do I need a short stay transit visa?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a transit visa for Japan if you do not enter the airport, regardless of nationality. This has been discussed on this [site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa) earlier as well, but with regard to a different nationality.