# Transit visa in US for Ecuador citizen

Tags: visas, usa, transit, singapore, ecuadorian-citizens

I am looking at a flight from Ecuador to Singapore which stops in JFK.

Do I need a transit visa if I am not leaving the airport?

The layover is four hours, the same on my return. Also stops in Toyota.
I have an Ecuador passport.

Comment: Yes, you need a transit visa, unless you already have another suitable visa such as a tourist visa.  You will need to clear immigration to make this transfer.

Comment: Did you mean Tokyo rather than Toyota? The USA transit question has been asked [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport) and a Japan transit question is [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa).