# 12hr layover in Tokyo NRT

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, layovers, nrt

Could not get the perfect answer from this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa)

---

Citizen of India.

Permanent resident in Canada.

Journey from New Delhi to Vancouver via Tokyo, NRT

---

My flight starts at,

New Delhi (DEL) to Tokyo (NRT), with flight duration, **7:35 PM Sunday to 6:50 AM, Monday, April**

As my connecting flight from Tokyo NRT to Vancouver is departing at **6:20 PM, Monday, April**, I would like to stay within Tokyo NRT airport for a layover duration of **11h 30m**

Am trying to understand, visa restrictions(if any) for 12 hr stay in Tokyo, NRT.

---

Question:

Does NRT airport authority allow passenger to stay(without any visa/document/pass) in airport for 12 hours(max) to board connecting flight?

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I would like to know, if I will be kicked out of the airport. Because, in that case, I should cancel my trip. As I do not have time to apply for visa to live outside Tokyo airport

Comment: @pnuts Your mentioning of some cases, makes me feel complex to travel via tokyo

Comment: You will be fine, see my answer

Comment: @Crazydre Are NRT services like Lounge, shower are paid service?

Comment: Never transited there, so don't know

Comment: In most countries you can just stay in the airside without problem because you don't go through passport control. Unless you're flying 2 different airlines and have to go through immigration to check in for the next flight, or you land on a country that prohibits airside transit then there's nothing to worry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layover at Narita, Japan. Do I need a transit visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9027/13777)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layover at Narita, Japan. Do I need a transit visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Query edited. I read this question before raising my query

Answer (score 11):

You will be able to stay airside at [Narita International Airport](http://www.narita-airport.jp/jp/dep_arr/connect/inter/), allowing you to transit without a visa, while waiting for your connecting flight to Canada. It has many services that can make the long wait easier, including shower and sleeping rooms, capsule hotel, smoking area, lounges, along with shops, restaurants and other amenities.

Comment: What does airside mean?

Comment: @overexchange in an airport there are landside (the side before going through security) and airside (after security) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport#Landside_and_airside_areas

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=jp&SUBSECTION=TW&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by virtually all airlines, including JAL:

> Transit without a visa: holders of onward tickets transiting on the
>     same calendar day

So yes, you can stay there for your connection

Comment: What is timatic?

Comment: @overexchange The database that check-in agents use to decide if you can fly or not. It is based on live information that the world's governments provide to IATA