# Transit Visa - Narita Airport for an Indian

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, canada, tokyo, nrt

I am traveling to Canada from India via Tokyo(Narita Airport) with a Layover of **10H30Minutes** and I will be arriving at **Terminal 1 and my connecting flight will be from Terminal 2.**

I contacted the Japan Embassy in Japan to confirm whether I need Transit Visa or not, they said yes because there is a change in the terminal and my ticket provider says that I do not need a transit visa.

> Can someone please tell me whether I need a Transit visa or not?

Carriers are Air India till Tokyo and then Air Canada.

Comment: Were both flights booked as a single booking (one PNR) or will you need to reclaim your luggage before checking in for your connecting flight? Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126144/do-we-need-a-visa-for-our-transfer-at-narita-tokyo?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Traveller Yes, Single booking, I have one PNR only.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: I think so as well. <g>