# How much is Transit Visa to Japan

Tags: japan, transit-visas

I'm a Russian citizen, currently studying in Canada traveling to Russia and have 16 hrs layover in Tokyo Narita. I know that I will need a transit visa. My question is if anyone knows how much the application for transit visa costs if I'll be applying in Canada?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layover at Narita, Japan. Do I need a transit visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa)

Comment: As noted in the linked Q&A, you don't appear to need a transit visa, and it's not clear why you think you do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've contacted Japanese Consulate-General in Vancouver and they told me that I will need a visa.

Comment: The linked Q&A is old; I wondered when citing it if might have aged poorly. @Arina, when you find out the answer — how much the visa costs — please come back and tell us. You can answer your own question here, and use the check mark to "accept" your answer as correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this website (Embassy of Japan in Canada)](https://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visa_fee.html), the cost of a transit visa is C$8.00.

By the way:

> No visa required for all nationalities if you are transiting through Japan within the same airport without leaving the secured area.

([Source.](https://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/transit_visa.html))

Comment: The question is whether it is possible (and practical) to spend a 16 hour layover in the secured area, which also may depend on the airlines operating each flight.

Comment: No, the question was how much the required tranist visa would cost. The follow-on (entirely appropriate, IMO) was would one really want to transit in that fashion; the "practicality" issue was not raised by the OP.

Comment: Not to mention you can still get a shore pass on arrival, so buying the transit visa in advance seems like unnecessary work.

Comment: @MichaelHampton But the airline may refuse to board the passenger without a transit visa if their system says that such a visa is needed. [Details (in Russian)](https://forum.awd.ru/viewtopic.php?p=1299647&sid=c96c66ba26c1fa266e1a6c2eef6ab1e9#p1299647).

Comment: @user77409 That system (called Timatic) says a transit visa is not needed and a shore pass can be obtained on arrival.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Apparently in 2010 it wasn't the case for Delta, according to the story in the link.

Comment: @user77409 You can always find a check-in agent who can't read or interpret the rules correctly. It's a little more complicated in that case because Guam, despite being part of the USA, has completely different immigration rules to the USA, and must be entered into Timatic as Guam (not USA). Otherwise it could return the wrong rules.