# Does Japan impose layover restrictions for travellers from India to the USA?

Tags: indian-citizens, japan, layovers

Are there any restrictions for a layover in Japan when I am travelling to the U.S. from India?

I am cleared to travel to the U.S. but not sure about layover requirements for Japan.

The connecting flight will be in 4 hours after I land in Japan.

Comment: Is this a single ticket?

Answer (score 3):

For the purposes of this answer I am assuming that you are:

- travelling on a single ticket;
- arrive and depart from the same airport (probably Narita) within the same calendar day; and
- do not need to re-check your bags or pass immigration for any other reason.

In such cases, [a transit visa or any other documentation was not required to transit Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9027). This still holds true during the pandemic: as long as you are not entering Japan (i.e. passing immigration), the Japanese government imposes no restrictions.

In the words of Japan Air Lines from [their website](https://www.jal.co.jp/jp/en/info/2020/other/flysafe/flights-service/quarantine-immigration/) (select guests entering Japan and then scroll down):

> Travelers who are not entering Japan and transferring directly to a third country by transit, are not required to submit any documents and undergo PCR tests.
>
> However, the following cases require entry into Japan. Please be informed that foreign nationals arriving from prohibited countries will not be allowed to enter Japan.
>
> - Transferring between Tokyo International Airport (Haneda Airport) and Narita International Airport
> - Travelers with a connecting flight out of Narita International Airport the following day

So this itinerary is possible.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I will be travelling on a single ticket, arrive and depart from the same airport (within 4 hours). Won't have to re-check the bags.

Looks like I should be able to travel. Thanks much.

Comment: @UtkarshMishra If this answer was what you needed, consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the little tick mark under the voting buttons. Also, welcome to Travel Stack Exchange; if you want to learn more about how this site works, feel free to take the [tour].