# Going Amsterdam to Miami via Toronto. Do bags go thru to MIA?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, pre-clearance, yyz

I am going from Amsterdam to Miami via Toronto. Do bags go thru to MIA?
Or do I also do customs in Canada ?

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but this question and its answers are at least related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/how-does-customs-work-if-my-layover-is-in-a-third-country

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant [airport page](https://www.torontopearson.com/Mobile/ConnectingGuide/Detail.aspx?arr=3):

> International flight to U.S. flight
>
> Canada Border Services Agency*** & U.S. Customs and Border Protection
>
> *** Some International to U.S. connecting flights at Terminal 1 do not require passengers to clear CBSA before clearing U.S. CBP inspection.

So, you will do cross the US border in Toronto but whether you need to pick up your luggage or not depends on the airline(s) involved. If you'd disclose the airline(s) involved, we could perhaps give you more advice. In general, for the future: you can't give too much information. Don't put personally identifiable information in the question but include *everything*, even if you think it can't possibly be relevant. This includes which country issued the passport (or passports!) you hold, additional travel documents like NEXUS, the date of your flight and the airlines you are flying. If you have flight numbers, even better. Yes, there have been cases when any of these affected the outcome of similar questions (dates can be relevant for example when construction or new terminal openings affect operations not to mention when they move the entire airport like they did with Hong Kong twenty years ago or Istanbul two weeks ago).

Comment: Regardless of whether they need to clear CBSA, they definitely need to clear US customs preclearance; won't they need to collect their luggage for the latter?  Or is there some system in place for clearing US customs without your luggage in hand?

Comment: When I board a plane to the USA in YVR I check in my luggage first then go to the preclearance. When I was sent to secondary they retrieved my luggage. The page linked above is also very clear on this order: collect luggage, clear CBSA, check in luggage, clear CBP.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've transited through Canada on a few occasions and never had to collect my luggage, despite clearing both Canadian and US border checkpoints.