# How long does it take to get a transit visa to travel through Canada?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, canada, indian-citizens

I hold an Indian passport and I'm travelling from the US to India via Canada. I know a transit Vlvisa is required in my case. However my agent warned that getting a transit visa may be delayed or it may get rejected. So I may want to change my itinerary while I still can (I have a 24-hour window) rather than take the risk.

Considering I have 3 months in hand, do you think it is really a risk? I live in Atlanta, Georgia and there is no Canada consulate around. That means I can't apply in person.

Can anybody share his/her experience with the Canada transit visa process. How long does it take? Are they finicky about the documents provided? Will they ask for more documents as follow-up, because that is going to add time to the processing time?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/canadian-visa-rules-for-flight-connections

Comment: 2 questions:  Is your US visa no longer valid?   Why do you think that there is no Canadian Consulate in Atlanta?

Comment: @Karlson: While there is a Canadian consulate in Atlanta, they don't appear to handle in-person visa applications;  the two [Canadian Visa Application Centers](http://www.csc-cvac.com/en-US/selfservice/cvac_welcome) in the USA are in NYC and LA (as of July 2015.)

Answer (score 5):

I suspect transit visas to be much quicker to process than even a regular visitor visa. If you're in the US, a *visitor* visa takes on average 28 to 41 days ([reference](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/temp/visitors.asp#west)), so with 3 months to spare I think you're on the safe side. I do suggest you apply at the LA office as it seems to be speedier than the NY one.

Quoting the CIC website:

> Most applications for transit visas are processed within a few weeks
>   or less. Processing times vary depending on the visa office.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are you a lawful permanent resident of the U.S. and have an alien registration card (Green Card) then you are eligible for an [eTA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) and:

> Most applicants get approved within minutes.  However, some applications can take several days to process so don’t wait until the last minute.